# Cast to Screen Using React Native

Tags: react-native

I am building a react-native app for playing videos and I would like to be able to cast those videos to the screen. The videos are coming from youtube and vimeo. Any idea how I can achieve that? Been looking at the react-native-google-cast library and it looks like it will require the users to have the Chromecast device which is a problem. It also won't work on iOS.

Comment: try this npm package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube-iframe).